# Adding a persisted object to another with Doctrine

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, associations, persist

I'm guessing that I just don't understand Doctrine fully yet, but here's what I'm doing:

I have a create account form where the user enters in typical stuff (user, pass, email) and I'm taking the data and first creating an email object and persisting that into my database:

```
//  Create a new email object.
$email = new Entities\EmailAddress();
$email->setEmailAddress($emailAddress);

//  Persist the new email object.
$this->doctrine->em->persist($email);
```

Then I'm creating a user object and persisting that to the database:

```
//  Create a new user object.
$user = new Entities\User();
$user->setUsername($username);
$user->setPassword($password);
$user->setSecurityLevel(0);
$user->getEmailAddresses()->add($email);

//  Persist the new user object.
$this->doctrine->em->persist($user);
```

The trouble starts with the `$user->getEmailAddresses()->add($email);` line (I was trying to follow an example, but I fear I'm no where close to doing this correctly).

The emails are defined as such in my `User.php` file:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EmailAddress", mappedBy="user")
 */
private $emails;
```

How can I add the recently persisted email object to my One-To-Many relationship `$emails` variable of my `User.php` class and persist the user to the database?

Answer (score 0):

You are close, but forget:

> $user->getEmailAddresses()->add($email);

and replace it with

```
$user->addEmails($email);
```

or

```
$user->setEmails($email);
```

depends on mapping